# Swift 2 Unable to remove optional binding

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, option-type

I am new in Swift and don't have much more idea on optional (! , ?). I tried to fetch data from plist, create Model and show to `UITableView`. Table data shows perfectly, but it shows with `Optional()` binding. I tried change ! to ? but unable to unwrap. Could you please, guide me to solve this problem.

Here is my code & output -

```
var fileName : String?
var dataArray : Array<SHQuesAns>?
```

For `fetch` data from `pList` -

```
func loadTableView(){
    dataArray = SHDataAccess.init(fname: fileName).arrayFromPlist()
    self.questionTableView.dataSource = self
    self.questionTableView.delegate=self
    self.questionTableView.reloadData()
}
```

`SHDataAccess` class -

```
import UIKit

var fileName : String!
class SHDataAccess: NSObject {

    init(fname:String?) {
        super.init()
        fileName = fname
    }

    func arrayFromPlist() -> Array <SHQuesAns>?{
        let dataPlists = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "plist")!)
        var dataObj : Array <SHQuesAns>? = Array()
        for data in dataPlists! {
            dataObj?.append(SHQuesAns.init(_dic: data as! NSDictionary))
        }
        return dataObj
    }

}
```

And `UITableView`  delegates -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  dataArray == nil ? 0 : dataArray!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let aCell = self.questionTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("qcell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SHQuestionCell
    let q : SHQuesAns = dataArray![indexPath.row]
    aCell.lblQuestion.text = "\(q.question)"
    return aCell
}
```

Here is the output -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove that Optional() text:

```
if let q = q.question as? String {

    aCell.lblQuestion.text = "\(q.question!)"

} else {

    aCell.lblQuestion.text = ""

}
```

The key is to unwrap the string contained in the question object so that when it is assigned to the text of the label, the Optional() part will not be included.

I’ve added support for the `nil` case if the question string is not defined.

Comment: i tried with your code but showing an error -
error 1: variable with getter/setter cannot have a initial value
error 2: Definition conflicts with previous unterminated string literal
error 3: let declaration can not be computer properties
error 4: computed property must have explicit type

Comment: @Shohrab Sorry, I forgot the `if` keyword that has been added now.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider not making your `dataObj` array optional? what purpose does it serve to be optional? Seems to me that if you need to add items to the array then you know it should exist and since you've initialized it it will always exist but then may be empty. Instead just make it implicitly unwrapped and then return nil if there's no data, then the objects of the array won't all be optional.

Comment: No problem! Glad it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

if you have a default in mind that you would want the optional string to fall back to, a simple fix would be something like:

`"\(q.question ?? "")"`

which will default to an empty string if q.question is nil

also: be careful of all of your force unwraps. it might make more sense to have some guard statements or if let unwraps.

and swift array's can be written like so: `var dataArray : [SHQuesAns]?`

but there aren't many situations where you need to differentiate between a nil array and an empty array so you can just do `var dataArray = [SHQuesAns]()` and save yourself the need to unwrap