# Remove optional string form dictionary

Tags: swift

I need to pass some params to web service but optional is also coming with them

```
if let birthYear = objPet?.birthYear {
        petDict = ["name": (objPet!.name!),
                   "birth_year": birthYear,
                   "gender": 1,
                   "breed": "test"]
    }
```

Console of **petDict**

```
{
    "birth_year" = "Optional(\"2000\")";
    breed = test;
    gender = 1;
    name = 2323;
}
```

I want     **"birth_year" = "2000"**. How can I do it.

**Class**

```
class Pet: NSObject {
    var name : String?
    var birthYear : String?
    var birthMonth : String?
    var gender : String?
    var breed : String?
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a double optional somewhere because it was not unwrapped completely.

Comment: Show us how `objPet?.birthYear` is declared.

Comment: Change the condition as **if let birthYear = objPet?.birthYear as! string {** . This may help.

Comment: @EricD I had updated question

Comment: Unwrap `objPet` *then* also unwrap its `birthYear` property. Sulthan was right: double Optional (your objPet is one and its property is also one).

Comment: replace with birthYear!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 Unable to remove optional binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749681/swift-2-unable-to-remove-optional-binding)

Comment: Your string is "Optional(2000)".  The problem is when the string is assigned to birthYear in the first place. THAT code needs to unwrap the optional year before creating the string it is assigning to birthYear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't how you are unwrapping `birthYear`.  Your problem is that the `String` stored in your `Pet` object for the `birthYear` property is literally `"Optional(2000)"`.

You are looking in the wrong place for the source of the problem.  You need to look at the code which creates the `Pet` object in the first place.

I did the following to recreate your issue in a Playground:

```
class Pet: NSObject {
    var name : String?
    var birthYear : String?
    var birthMonth : String?
    var gender : String?
    var breed : String?
}

let objPet: Pet? = Pet()

objPet?.name = "Fido"

let year: Int? = 2000
objPet?.birthYear = "\(year)"   // you have something like this somewhere

if let birthYear = objPet?.birthYear {
    let petDict = ["name": (objPet!.name!),
               "birth_year": birthYear,
               "gender": 1,
               "breed": "test"]
    print(petDict)
}
```

Output:

> ```
> {
>     "birth_year" = "Optional(2000)";
>     breed = test;
>     gender = 1;
>     name = Fido;
> }
> ```

If you change `objPet?.birthYear = "\(year)"` to `objPet?.birthYear = "\(year!)"`, then the `"Optional"` goes away.  This demonstrates that the problem is with the `String` stored in the object and not how you are unwrapping that `String` when you create your `petDict`.

Comment: Thanks its very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to:

```
if let pet = objPet {
   if let birthYear = pet.birthYear {
        petDict = ["name": (pet.name!),
                   "birth_year": birthYear,
                   "gender": 1,
                   "breed": "test"]
    }
}
```

should help

Edit: you should probably safely unwrap pet.name also

Comment: Please don't advocate using `!`, the "crash operator". Always use safe unwrapping instead, like with `if let` or `guard` for example.